# Problem in connecting with oracle database through laravel

Tags: laravel, oracle, tns

I am getting the following error while connecting with the oracle database through laravel8 -

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Comment: your client is unable to locate its tnsnames.ora file to resolve the connect identifier. Can you post a sample of your connection string and your tnsnames.ora, masking any public IP addresses or other sensitive data?

Comment: @pmdba I put HOST in TNS value and it worked, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check your oracle connection's configuration.
According to [this](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8) a valid format on config/database.php is:

```
'oracle' => [
    'driver' => 'oracle',
    'host' => 'oracle.host.ip.here',
    'port' => '1521',
    'database' => 'xe',
    'service_name' => 'sid_alias',
    'username' => 'hr',
    'password' => 'hr',
    'charset' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
]
```

Ask your DBA if you are not sure of the database or service name you have to use in your case.

Comment: I put HOST in TNS value and it worked, thank you so much for your help.